# git-svn: branch renamed in svn repository, how do I tell git-svn?

Tags: git, git-svn

I'm using git-svn to track an svn repository with several branches.  One of the server branches I've been working with has been renamed in the svn repository.  Git-svn doesn't seem to understand what's happened.  How can I tell git-svn what happened?

Comment: I'm assuming you did git svn fetch/rebase? What do you see when you run git branch -a ? You should hopefully be seeing the branch under its old name as well as under its new name.

Comment: This is something I've struggled with as well.  My company relocates branches to a "history" folder after they have been merged (in SVN).  This means that every branch we have basically is two branches.  One is all of the work that was done on the branch, the other is a single commit, when it was moved to its new "archive" location.  I have yet to find an elegant solution to this issue.  Presumably grafting the two branches together would have the desired effect, but I haven't tried this yet.

Answer (score -2):

You should probably update your `.git/config` file to make your svn url points to a correct branch:

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
    url = https://my.repo/svn/MyProj/newbranch/
```